# why does `\dt` not show any table under a database?

Tags: postgresql, psql

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# \c students
You are now connected to database "students" as user "postgres".
students=# create table student(name char(30), gender char(30), birthday date)
students-# \dt
No relations found.
students-# insert into student value ('Tom', 'male', '11-21-2000')
students-# \dt
No relations found.
```

I was wondering why `\dt` doesn't show any table under database `students`, even after I create a new table `student` and after I insert a record into the table?

Thanks.

Comment: Try the command `\dt *.` to list all tables under all schemas. Does your table show up then?

Comment: `\dt *.` doesn't show the table in `students`, although a list of tables in other databases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pay close attention to the prompts:

```
students=# create ...
students-# \dt
No relations found.
students-# insert ...
students-# \dt
No relations found.
```

Note that it starts out with `=#` and then becomes `-#`. The `-#` prompt means "I'm waiting for you to complete a statement". Then if we look at your `create` and `insert` "statements", we'll notice that **they're not terminated with semicolons so they don't get to the database.** The `\...` commands are executed directly by `psql` so they don't need semicolon terminators, they're executed as soon as you hit <kbd>return</kbd> (or <kbd>enter</kbd> if you have one of *those* keyboards).

(The `#` means that you're the "root" user for the database, non-root users get `>` and the difference between `->` and `=>` is much easier to see without all the extra lines in `#`.)

Comment: Thanks. What does "The \... commands are executed directly by psql" mean? Are "The \... commands" executed by the client `psql` only and not by the server? What are the opposite situations?

Comment: The backslash commands aren't SQL statements, they're instructions to the `psql` shell itself rather than bits of SQL for the database: [**"Anything you enter in psql that begins with an unquoted backslash is a psql meta-command that is processed by psql itself. These commands make psql more useful for administration or scripting. Meta-commands are often called slash or backslash commands."**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html).

Comment: They may involve communicating with the server, `\dt` for example will query the database's system tables.

Answer (score 7):

I found this helps:

```
\dt+ *
```

Shows tables and names from only the pg_catalog

I also found this will display all tables in that database:

```
select * from pg_catalog.pg_tables;
```

Then seeing my tables, and their schema prefix, I can display just my tables again like this:

```
\dt+ <the_schema_name>.*
```